# Changing object right before PHP serialises it

Tags: php, serialization, reflection

I have the following class tree:

```
class A /* Base class */
{ 
  private/protected/public $state 
} 

class B extends A /* Auto generated class, not to be modified */
{
  private $v
  public function getV() { return $this->v; }
  public function setV($val) { $this->v = $val; }
}

class C extends B { /* Custom code */ }
```

There is only one class A. There are multiple classes like class B, and all of those classes will have a subclass like C. Class B gets auto-generated and should not be modified.

I am storing objects of type(s) C in the session. What I want to do is to store some state information in every instance, just before PHP gets it serialised, and that will do something with it when it's unserialised. I want all this to be implemented in class A.

Considering, I need to use either `__sleep()` or `Serializable` interface. Using `__sleep` is out of the question, because of what the PHP manual says:

> It is not possible for __sleep() to return names of private properties in parent classes. Doing this will result in an E_NOTICE level error. Instead you may use the Serializable interface.

Meaning that if I sleep an instance of class C, I'll loose the private variables declared in B. So I want to use Serializable, but for some reason, I simply can't get it to do what I want.

In essence, I would like the object to be serialised just as if I didn't implement any serialisation stuff myself, I just want to add information to `$state` right before it happens. I've tried covering all data with `ReflectionObject->getProperties()`, but I can't seem to find the right way to fetch and set the private values in class B to be serialised and unserialised.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the Reflection classes. You'll have to get the properties of the class itself and each of it's parent classes. Getting and setting the property values can be done using `ReflectionProperty`'s `getValue` and `setValue` methods, combined with `setAccessible` to get access to private and protected properties. Combining those, I came up with the following code:

```
<?php

class A implements Serializable /* Base class */
{
  protected $state;

  public function serialize()
  {
    $this->state = "something";
    return serialize($this->_getState());
  }

  public function unserialize($data)
  {
    $this->_setState(unserialize($data));
  }

  protected function _getState()
  {
    $reflClass = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
    $values = array();
    while ($reflClass != null)
    {
      foreach ($reflClass->getProperties() as $property)
      {
        if ($property->getDeclaringClass() == $reflClass)
        {
          $property->setAccessible(true);
          $values[] = array($reflClass->getName(), $property->getName(), $property->getValue($this));
        }
      }
      $reflClass = $reflClass->getParentClass();
    }
    return $values;
  }

  protected function _setState($values)
  {
    foreach ($values as $_)
    {
      list($className, $propertyName, $propertyValue) = $_;

      $property = new ReflectionProperty($className, $propertyName);
      $property->setAccessible(true);
      $property->setValue($this, $propertyValue);
    }
  }

}

class B extends A /* Auto generated class, not to be modified */
{
  private $v;
  public function getV() { return $this->v; }
  public function setV($val) { $this->v = $val; }
}

class C extends B { /* Custom code */ }

$instance = new C();
$instance->setV("value");
$s = serialize($instance);

$instance2 = unserialize($s);
var_dump($instance, $instance2);
```

Which seems to do what you want.